# Use data object in php from post/get method

Tags: php, decoding, endpoint

I wanted to use data below

[call looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XGED.png)

I tried

```
echo json_decode($_GET);
```

but is still empty. Is there any way how to get this data? 
Thanks

[Sending(JS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufHva.png)

GET Mehtod

[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWZeE.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3hpa.png)

[response with param in link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ste4G.png)

POST Mehtod

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YhSW.png)

[PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxCEe.png)

Comment: echo $_GET["following"]; try this

Comment: `$_GET` will never be a string containing JSON. If anything it contains an array of data already decoded from URL-encoded values.

Comment: `json_decode` is for turning a JSON string into a PHP data structure. `$_GET` is never a string, it's an array of query-string variables. If you're posting a single JSON string as a query parameter, you need to refer to it by name. If you're posting multiple, then you don't need to decode them, it's already done. It also doesn't make sense to call `echo` on a PHP object - what output do you actually want?

Comment: if possible post your $.get code here

Answer (score 0):

json_decode is used to convert string to json structure.

$_GET[""] should work with parameters.

PHP SIDE

```
echo $_GET["following"]; 
echo $_GET["newest"]; 
echo $_GET["offset"];
```

HTML SCRIPT

```
$.get('/ajaxcalls/loadposts.php', {following:0,orderBy:"newest", offset: 0}, function(data){
});
```

If you are using get method then use $_GET and i you are using POST method then use $_POST

In your case you have to use $_POST

Comment: i tried, there is result [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3yhK.png

Comment: cannot help you further, without seeing the SERVER side and JAVSCRIPT code

Comment: send me the function in line number 49 of index.js

Comment: i added JS and PHP side

Comment: You are using post method!

Comment: Change $_GET to $_POST

Comment: give some echo in top of the php page and see if it is coming.

Comment: change your url to  "/ajaxcalls/loadposts.php?orderBy=newest&offset=0"

Comment: just to see the output

Comment: that means you are getting data?

Comment: if YES then please change everything to POST

Comment: added images again, i think there is problem with the recognition of data object